# How google finds xyz.com has good backlinks for specific category

Tags: google-search

How does it finds the back links of the websites and how does it remember. I have heard robots.txt.

Comment: If we knew how Google does what they do they would be as famous as they are right now. Or very useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's already searching the web, remember. It doesn't need to find backlinks, it just needs to remember the forward links it found.

Comment: But the pagerank is totally based on backlinks right ? then how does it know the backlinks of websites ?

Comment: 1. Pagerank hasn't been based purely on backlinks for over a decade.
2. If I look at webpage A and see a link to webpage B, then I know that webpage B is linked from A. Google only knows about links from pages it sees on the rest of its search (which is why backlinks from non-robotable resources don't help pagerank).